# Cannot form weak reference to instance of class NSTextView

Tags: swift

Using Swift only, here's my code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow
    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextView

    @IBAction func displaySomeText(AnyObject) {
        textField.insertText("A string...")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

In the interface builder, I have an object hooked up to receive input from a button, then the output goes to a text view.  I'm trying to get the text view to populate with some text when I hit the button.

I tried this with a text field as well, and didn't get the error, but got a "dong" error sound and it didn't do anything else.  In Objective-C, you had to use the `(assign)` parameter to get this to work from what I understand.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016527/strong-and-weak-references-in-swift) describes how to use a weak reference in swift.

Comment: Tried using weak in front of var, but no difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `@IBOutlet var scrollView: NSScrollView` instead of `@IBOutlet var textField: NSTextView`.
Then create a property returns documentView in scrollView.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: NSScrollView

    var textField: NSTextView {
        get {
            return scrollView.contentView.documentView as NSTextView
        }
    }

    @IBAction func displaySomeText(AnyObject) {
        textField.insertText("A string...")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - got another error.  'NSTextView' is not convertible to 'NSScrollView'

Comment: Did you use Interface Builder to make a link of scrollView? I've executed above code successfully.

Comment: Can you share the project file, please?

Comment: @Steve [See this helloworld.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4415859/helloworld.zip) which is created with XCode 6 Beta (6A215l).

Comment: Thank you!  So you really did it completely different.  The book had me creating references between the button and the text view tied to the function, but I only see one reference in your xib.  I'm going to study this in more detail today.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot store a weak reference to an `NSTextView` due to historical issues with Cocoa and AppKit.  See [details in the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#weak-unavailable-types).  `NSTextView` is marked as `NS_AUTOMATED_REFCOUNT_WEAK_UNAVAILABLE` in [NSTextView.h](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/9fc3ed0ad0345950ac25c28695b0427846eea966/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSTextView.h#L60), there are also [a few other classes](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/search?p=4&q=NS_AUTOMATED_REFCOUNT_WEAK_UNAVAILABLE&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) to lookout.

Have you tried a Swift unowned reference instead of weak, which is kind of like Objective-C's assign (what you'd use for an `NSTextView` outlet in Objective-C)?

Comment: Whoa, that's obscure: 243 results on Google. Here's the full Swift error message, in case people Google this confused: "Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x...) of class NSTextView. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation." Can't even see the `NS_AUTOMATED_REFCOUNT_WEAK_UNAVAILABLE` tag in the Swift "headers"!

Comment: Swift 3.1 appears to have lifted this restriction.

Comment: @Feldur still happens on 10.11, [behaviour changed in 10.12](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/9fc3ed0ad0345950ac25c28695b0427846eea966/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSTextView.h#L59-L61).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate what you described. I have created a new OS X app using Xcode 6 beta 7. I have dropped a button and text view in the main form.

I think your problem is that the connection to the Text View object is not correct for some reason. To make things easier, I've connected the objects using control-drag, which adds the required code automatically. So first I've connected the Text View. To do this click on the text view object until Text View is selected. When I do this in my version of Xcode, the first time I click on the object, *Bordered Scroll View* is selected. Clicking on it again then selects *Clip View*. Finally, clicking on it again selects *Text View*. Now I control-drag from the object to the AppDelegate.swift code (It helps to display the Assistant Editor so that you have your form UI and code side-by-side).

By doing this I get this little window:

[image]

Notice that the type is NSTextView and the storage is Weak. I've only had to add the name and click Connect. This adds the following code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: NSTextView!
```

The code is almost exactly like the one you have, except for the `!` at the end of the line, which forces to unwrap the value of textField.

Just with that, the code as you have it in your question should work.

The other thing I would suggest is not to use `insertText`. According to Apple's documentation for [NSTextView.insertText](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/insertText:):

> This method is the entry point for inserting text typed by the user
>   and is generally not suitable for other purposes. Programmatic
>   modification of the text is best done by operating on the text storage
>   directly.

As far as I understand this, *programmatic modification of the text by operating on the text storage directly* means dealing with NSText, which NSTextView inherits from. So instead, use [NSText.string](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/string). This is how the click button action looks in my code:

```
@IBAction func displaySomeText(sender: NSButton) {
    // If you want to add a new 'A string... ' every time you click the button
    textField.string! += "A string... "
    // otherwise just use
    //textField.string = "A string..."
}
```

I have added the Button Action in the same way as I've added the Text View Outlet, by control-dragging, and, in this case, selecting `NSButton` as the sender, instead of leaving the default `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

@IBOutlet automatically makes a property weak IIRC, but weak doesn't automatically make a property optional. But it is required that a weak property be made optional, as the property could at any time be deallocated and made nil. So you have to declare your @IBOutlets as optional.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow? // Optional
    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextView?

    @IBAction func displaySomeText(AnyObject) {
        textField?.insertText("A string...") // Only call the method if the object exists
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this code as well, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "dong" error suggest a responder chain problem? What if you call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field before inserting the text?

Comment: No luck removing the "dong" when trying that method on the text field first.  Here's a pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/A2ZaXXPD

Answer (score -2):

To create a weak reference user the `weak` keyword:

example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView
```

In your case

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextView
```

Comment: @IBOutlets are automatically made weak in swift.

Comment: I had the same error and had to *remove* weak, at which point it worked fine. The exact text in my source is `@IBOutlet var CommentsTextView: NSTextView!`